# Using jQuery, how do I change the input element's value when I click outside of the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" size="13px" name="username" id="username" value="enter username" onclick='document.signIn.username.value = ""' />

$(function() {
    $('#messageBoxSignIn').click(function() {
        $('#username').val('');
        $('#username').focus();
    });
});
```

I currently have jQuery code making the input value to nothing and focusing the cursor into the textarea `#username` when a button with ID `#messageBoxSignIn` is clicked. However, when a user clicks outside of the textarea `#username` without entering anything, I want the input value to return back to *"enter username"*.

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps just a `placeholder` attribute. But worth to know about [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If HTML5 is okay for you, you can use `placeholder` attribute for this. You don't need jQuery.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
```

You may try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val('Enter Username');
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#username').on('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val('Enter Username');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="enter username" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='enter username'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'enter username') {this.value=''}">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/ur9ctku2/

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong.  You need to add attribute 'placeholder' to the input element.  You don't need all this javascript.  The browser will do the replacement on its own.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp